# How to use an array from one method in another method without making it global in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing, return-value

The code below asks a user about their bus routes and some information about them. There is a recurring error within the program.

I can't use the array within the second method. I tried making the array a global variable but then errors occurred. How can I access the array variable from the `busRoutes()` method in the `decisionMaking()`.

If the only way to do this is to make it a global variable, could you show me how to prevent errors from occurring?

```
public class question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        busRoutes();
        decisionMaking();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    public static void busRoutes() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many bus routes are there");

        int routes = sc.nextInt();
        String[][] array = new String[routes][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < routes ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the bus route");
            System.out.println("What is the bus route");
            array[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Start Location");
            array[i][1] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("End Location");
            array[i][2] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Who is the driver for bus route " + array[i][0]);
            array[i][3] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }


    public static void decisionMaking() {
        System.out.println("Do you want to 1) Print all bus routes 2) Start a new day 3) Quit ? ");

        int decision = sc.nextInt();
        if (decision == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
            }
        }

        else if (decision == 3) {
            return;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

}
}

Comment: You could pass it to the second method as a parameter?

Comment: This code isn't even valid, How are you running it/

Comment: The code before had no methods. Just the main and it worked fine. I added methods afterwards and errors happened such as the one I stated. array is declared in the first method so it can be used in second method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `sc` and `array` isn't visible to `decisionMaking` You can either make it a global variable or pass it to that method.

You shouldn't make everything global but pass it as a param if it's not being modified.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    busRoutes();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

removed `decisionMaking` from main method. and added 2 params to it.

`public static void decisionMaking(Scanner sc, String[][] array)`

now we pass it from `busRoutes`

```
public static void busRoutes() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many bus routes are there");
    int routes = sc.nextInt();
    String[][] array = new String[routes][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < routes; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the bus route");
        System.out.println("What is the bus route");
        array[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Start Location");
        array[i][1] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("End Location");
        array[i][2] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Who is the driver for bus route " + array[i][0]);
        array[i][3] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    decisionMaking(sc, array);
}
```

Here is the full code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        busRoutes();
        System.exit(0);
    }


    public static void busRoutes() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many bus routes are there");
        int routes = sc.nextInt();
        String[][] array = new String[routes][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < routes; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the bus route");
            System.out.println("What is the bus route");
            array[i][0] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Start Location");
            array[i][1] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("End Location");
            array[i][2] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Who is the driver for bus route " + array[i][0]);
            array[i][3] = sc.nextLine();
        }
        decisionMaking(sc, array);
    }


    public static void decisionMaking(Scanner sc, String[][] array) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to 1) Print all bus routes 2) Start a new day 3) Quit ? ");
        int decision = sc.nextInt();
        if (decision == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));

            }
        } else if (decision == 3) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your first method (`getBusRoutesFromUser`) completes, `return` the array to your `main` method (and assign it to a new variable there. Then, when calling the second method (`determineNextAction`), pass it as a parameter to that method.

Note that method names tend to be verbs/actions by convention, since they're *doing* something. Likewise, you'll want to choose variable names that are meaningful to the context (so `arrays` would be too generic).

```
public class BusRoutes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] routeDetails = getBusRoutesFromUser();
        determineNextAction(routeDetails);
    }

    public static void getBusRoutesFromUser() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many bus routes are there");
        int routes = sc.nextInt();

        String[][] routeDetails = new String[routes][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < routes; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the bus route");
            System.out.println("What is the bus route");
            routeDetails[i][0] = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Start Location");
            routeDetails[i][1] = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("End Location");
            routeDetails[i][2] = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Who is the driver for bus route " + routeDetails[i][0]);
            routeDetails[i][3] = sc.nextLine();
        }

        return routeDetails;
    }


    public static void determineNextAction(String[][] routeDetails) {
        // Use routeDetails array here...
    }

}
```

Further Reading:

1. [Returning a value from a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)
2. [Passing information to a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)